# Python sklearn - could not convert string to float Error

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a DecisionTreeClassifier:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

dataset = pd.read_csv('./vgsales.csv')
X = dataset[["Name"]]
Y = dataset[["Global_Sales"]]

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

When running `model.fit` line, I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-84aa7640ed28> in <module>
     12 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)
     13 
---> 14 model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    896         """
    897 
--> 898         super().fit(
    899             X, y,
    900             sample_weight=sample_weight,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    154             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    155             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
--> 156             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
    157                                        validate_separately=(check_X_params,
    158                                                             check_y_params))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    428                 # :(
    429                 check_X_params, check_y_params = validate_separately
--> 430                 X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
    431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    432             else:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    614                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    615                 else:
--> 616                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    617             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    618                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order, like)
    100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, like=like)
    101 
--> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    103 
    104 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1897 
   1898     def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1899         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1900 
   1901     def __array_wrap__(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order, like)
    100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, like=like)
    101 
--> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    103 
    104 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Tiger Woods PGA Tour 14'
```

I have already tried to use the code mentioned in this link ->
[sklearn-LinearRegression: could not convert string to float: '--'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092914/sklearn-linearregression-could-not-convert-string-to-float)

When I use apply() method to convert to numeric/float, all my data values are changing to **NaN**.

The dataset I am using is https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example in which all columns have been converted to "tree friendly type". You might not want to convert all columns, but depends on the problem you're trying to solve anyway. Works for this example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

dataset = pd.read_csv('./vgsales.csv')
dataset.Publisher = dataset.Publisher.astype(str)

for column in dataset.columns:
    temp_new = le.fit_transform(dataset[column].astype('category'))
    dataset.drop(labels=[column], axis="columns", inplace=True)
    dataset[column] = temp_new

X = dataset[["Name"]]
Y = dataset[["Global_Sales"]]

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

Now I'll continue to give you some tips here.. first of all if you're planing on actually training a useful classifier you should probably

- check the unique counts for each column before using them, if you have too many any tree model will have a hard time.
  In this case you have for example 11493 unique names.
- It looks like you're trying to do regression ( predict a number ). I.e use a regressor instead.
- In reality you should always go for a Random Forest instead of a Decision Tree, they are simply better (less prone to overfitting ). Decsion Trees are not really used.

Answer (score 0):

Machine Learning model can't handle text data, you have to convert it into numerical form, use LabelEncoder like this

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder    
dataset = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')
dataset = dataset.dropna()

dataset[['Name', 'Platform', 'Genre', 'Publisher']] = dataset[['Name', 'Platform', 'Genre', 'Publisher']].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

X = data[features]
y = data[target]

X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X)

## train my models

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).